# Flutter access firebase user email from different class

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am stuck for hours now on this problem.

I have no problem to access the `final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;`when the getCurrentUser function is defined and called in the same class (SlateScreen).

My SlateScreen Class ad MessageStream Class are both in the same .dart file. So this here works:

```
final firestore = Firestore.instance;

/// loggedInUser variable for fetching the user email later
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = DatabaseMethods();

class TheSlateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'theslate_screen';
  @override
  _TheSlateScreenState createState() => _TheSlateScreenState();
}

class _TheSlateScreenState extends State<TheSlateScreen> {

final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
// call getCurrentUser in initState    
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrenUser();       
  }

getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// fetch the email from my getCurrentUser function
final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
```

But I get "The getter email was called on null" error if I define my getCurrentUser() function in the DatabaseMethods Class, and then call it in the SlateScreen class' via

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseMethods.getCurrentUser(_auth);
  }
```

My DatabaseMethods Class:

```
class DatabaseMethods {    
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  getCurrentUser(FirebaseAuth _auth) async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);          
    }
  }
```

I tried all kind of adjustments, but didn t get anywhere...

**UPDATE / SOLUTION:**

Thanks to the the anwsers provided, I found a way:

in my DatabaseMethods class I simply return the user:

```
Class DatabaseMethods {
  getCurrentUser(FirebaseAuth _auth) async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();

      if (user != null) {
        return user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

and in the SlateScreen Class, I am using a helper function that I can call in initState():

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    logInUser(_auth);
  }

  logInUser(_auth) async {
    loggedInUser = await DatabaseMethods().getCurrentUser(_auth);
  }
```

Comment: How is `MessagesStream` used?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I updated my solution in the question. Saved me another few hours of trial and error.

Comment: why isn't `FirebaseAuth.instance.getUser()` viable option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `loggedInUser`, just do the following:

```
loggedInUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet:

```
// fetch the email from my getCurrentUser function
final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
```

The `loggedInUser` variable is only set once the `getCurrentUser` method has completed.  So you can't just do `loggedInUser.email` anywhere in your code, but can only do that after you've made sure `getCurrentUser` has completed.

So this would work fine:

```
await databaseMethods.getCurrentUser(_auth);
final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;
```

---

Given what you shared, it **may** be able to add that `await` in your `initState`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  await databaseMethods.getCurrentUser(_auth);
}
```